# Python - How to flatten nested JSON containing serialized JSON and list at deep level?

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON with the following structure (example):

```
{
  "data": {
      "items": [
        {
            "description": "{\"size\":[{\\\"dimensions\\\":[{\\\"length\\\":200,\\\"width\\\":100}]}]}"
            "timestamp": 1196320984,
        },
        {
            "description": "{......}"
            "timestamp": 1232918783,
        },
        .......
      ],
      "locations": [
      ..............
      ]
   }
}
```

As you can see, there are dict values which are serialized and contain list within it.

I tried using json.loads() followed by pandas.json_normalized(), it only flattens up to description.size i.e its value is still a list like this:

```
 "description.size": [{"dimensions":[{"length":200,"width":100}]}]
```

I am expecting it to deconstruct into:

```
"description.size.dimensions.length": 200
"description.size.dimensions.width": 100
```

Anybody has an idea?